# How to hide content block at SF market cloud email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, ssjs

I need to show images that returned from the other endpoint at market cloud email. Sometimes the endpoint can return 3 images, sometimes it return 1 image or no image. I tried to use image block to show images, i also changed the image url at the block HTML. for example, i changed the html like this(i replaced the original image url with my image url, it is an ampscript value "%%=v(@imageUrls1)=%%"):

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
   <tr>
      <td align="center">
       <img data-assetid="4855" src="%%=v(@imageUrls1)=%%" alt="" height="301" width="391" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 301px; width: 391px; border: 0px;">
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

however, is there is no image return, this block still exist. Is there any way to hide it? I tried to use SSJS, but i didn't find the proper api to use. any suggestion?

Comment: Is the image url  being stored in a data extension against each subscriber?

Comment: yes, imageurl is already stored as ampscript for each subscriber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a conditional statement in AMPscript:

```
%%[IF NOT EMPTY(@imageUrls1) THEN]%%
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
<tr><td align="center">    
<img data-assetid="4855" src="%%=v(@imageUrls1)=%%" alt="" height="301" width="391" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 301px; width: 391px; border: 0px;">    
</td></tr></table>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

It will only display the image if there is a value available for the `@imageUrls1` variable.

You can replicate this for all three images.

Comment: thank you. very helpful